How to Avoid Undefiened behaviour while using GetAdaptersAddresses
When calling GetAdaptersAddresses() you are required to pass a IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES* buffer as AdapterAddresses
GetAdaptersAddresses()
IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES
IPHLPAPI_DLL_LINKAGE ULONG GetAdaptersAddresses(
  [in]      ULONG                 Family,
  [in]      ULONG                 Flags,
  [in]      PVOID                 Reserved,
  [in, out] PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES AdapterAddresses,
  [in, out] PULONG                SizePointer
);

I originally thought this buffer could be a so std::unique_ptr<IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES[]> as per the example below
std::optional<sockaddr> GetAdapterIPv4SockAddr(const std::string& name)
{
    int neededSize = 128;
    std::unique_ptr<IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES[]> adapterAddresses = std::make_unique<IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES[]>(neededSize);
    ULONG dwBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES) * neededSize;

    DWORD dwStatus = GetAdaptersAddresses(
        AF_UNSPEC,
        GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX | GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_GATEWAYS,
        NULL,
        adapterAddresses.get(),
        &dwBufLen);

    if (dwStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return false;

    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pAdapterInfo = adapterAddresses.get();

    do
    {
        if (strcmp(pAdapterInfo->AdapterName, name.c_str()) == 0)
        {
            PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS address = nullptr;
            address = pAdapterInfo->FirstUnicastAddress;
            while (address != nullptr && address->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family != AF_INET)
                address = address->Next;
        }

        if (address != nullptr)
            return address->Address.lpSockaddr
        else
            return std::nullopt;
        }

        pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next;
    } while (pAdapterInfo);

    return std::nullopt;
}

However, on closer inspection, I've found that GetAdaptersAddresses() will also put other sturtures and strings into the provided adapterAddresses buffer
I.e. I would have a buffer containing the following (as an example)
Adapter_1, <Structures/strings referenced by Adapter_1>, Adapter_2, <Structures/strings referenced by Adapter_2>, ...

Where Adapter_* is an IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES and Adapter_1->Next would point to Adapter_2
And fields AdapterName, FirstUnicastAddress etc. would be pointing into additonal structs/strings also stored in adapterAddresses buffer
This suggests to me that my use of std::unique_ptr<IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES[]> is incorrect.
However, I'm unsure as to how to correct the code to avoid any C++ Undefined behaviours.
I suspect that I could use a std::unique_ptr<std::byte[]> and rely on implicit object creation (possibly with a std::launder?)
That leaves me with the call to GetAdaptersAddresses() which expects the buffer to be a pointer of type IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES*.
Requiring me to perform a reinterpret_cast, which would violate strict aliasing rules right?

std::unique_ptr<IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES[]> adapterAddresses = std::make_unique<IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES[]>(neededSize); or std::unique_ptr<std::byte[]> are too complicated and are not good C++. They should be std::vector<std::byte>.

You can use HeapAlloc/HeapFree or malloc/free or new[]/delete[] for this. I'd use make_unique_for_overwrite<IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES[]>(number);  or, as you may need to try twice to get the correct size, use a std::vector<IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES> which starts small the first try and then resize() it the second call when you know how much memory you need.

would violate strict aliasing rules right? - not so strictly with exceptional char and byte arrays. The suggested std::vector<IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES> in the other comment is wrong, it must be std::vector<std::byte>, because the returned data does not contained sequenced IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES elements.

Sidenote: Instead of if (strcmp(pAdapterInfo->AdapterName, name.c_str()) == 0) you could do if (name == pAdapterInfo->AdapterName) since apparently, AdapterName is guaranteed to be null terminated.

Just pass std::vector<std::byte> with a required size, and cast vector's .data() to IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES*. There is no strict aliasing rule violation because GetAdaptersAddresses() places IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES at .data().

I should note that the example is simplified somewhat, I'm using std::unique_ptr so that I can return it to the caller (by 'swap'ing it with a caller passed std::unique_ptr)

@273K Re: "the returned data does not contained sequenced IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES ..." - Oh, do you know what's placed before/after the actual IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES structs in memory? Is there some padding other than what the struct itself requires?

@Ted Lyngmo It contains data that is referenced by IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES. i.e. AdapterName is a pointer to a char string stored outside the structure, but within the buffer, and seemingly before the next IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES in the list

@TedLyngmo, it places data such as AdapterName, DnsSuffix, Description, FriendlyName between IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES storages, i.e. between &ip_adapter_address and ip_adapter_address.Next.

Got it guys! :-)

@Ted Lyngmo The example I've provided is somewhat simplified. I had removed code to retry with a larger buffer if I get a returned dwStatus of ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW. The required size would be returned via dwBufLen

@TheLastRar Yeah I know, but it kept returning the same value even though I provided it with a buffer of the correct size. It turned out I had an UB in my own code so, no biggie. :) I got it working now.

If the resize is unlikely, more optimized option would be: auto addr_buf=std::make_unique_for_overwrite<std::byte[]>(addr_buf_size);. This suppresses initial zeroing invoked by other methods, which may marginally improve performance.

@TedLyngmo windows API is not what I would publish as production code. It's quite messy - full of premature micro optimizations. Functions get long lists of parameters, with little abstraction and lots of type-punning/unions. I am always stuck between wrapping them for better interface, or using them raw for simplicity and succinctness.

@Red.Wave :-) Yes, I'm familiar with some parts in it. Did some stuff with overlapping buffers for audio some 20 years ago. It wasn't too bad once I got used to it but the whole API design is "all over the place".  You can tell that it's been through a few paradigm shifts over the years.

@TedLyngmo it's just bad design. I did some time with QNX a few years ago; it was full of bugs, but the API was very well organized; there were a lot of patterns that  you could use in templates with a modern toolchain. POSIX has good interface too. Windows is just a mess in all aspects.

@Red.Wave yeah, it's for sure very different from any *nix-like system where everything's a file + a ton of ioctls. In Windows there is one API per "thing" and they follow different patterns. Messy...

@Red.Wave I've had a much harder time getting adapter information from POSIX apis, so I'd have disagree in this particular instance.

Also, Do I need to do anything specific to trigger implicit object creation, or will reading the returned data (such as AdapterName) be sufficient?
